# Twitter-Bootstrap-3 tabs data-toggle href redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using .Net MVC5 with Bootstrap3 how do I get my sub-menu of tabs to redirect to a different view while keeping the `data-toggle="tabs"`?

I am trying to have a top level menu with a sub menu and keep the data-toggle functionality so show what tabs you are on.

If I remove the `data-toggle="tabs"` from the sub-menu section the redirect works just fine however I lose the ability to show what tab you are on.

If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9n7mt6zq/1/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="one">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">One SubMenu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">One SubMenu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">One SubMenu 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="two">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">Two SubMenu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">Two SubMenu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">Two SubMenu 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="three">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">Three SubMenu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">Three SubMenu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About" data-toggle="tab">Three SubMenu 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery error the way it stands.

> Unhandled exception at line 1864, column 2 in http://localhost:34607/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Home/About

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding a custom field to my ViewModel which has the active tabpage.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs">
<li @(Model.ViewMode == 1 ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Item1", "List", new { viewMode = 1 })</li>
<li @(Model.ViewMode == 2 ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Item2", "List", new { viewMode = 2 })</li>
<li @(Model.ViewMode == 3 ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Item3", "List", new { viewMode = 3 })</li>
</ul>
```